# Add 10 minute cron job to Ubuntu package

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, cron

I need to install some cron jobs with my Ubuntu installation package. The ones that run every day or hour are easy: I can just create a symlink from `/etc/cron.daily` to my script.

However, I also have a script that I would like to run every 10 minutes. There is no such thing as `/etc/cron.minutely`. Also I am not sure how to edit crontab without using the interactive editor (`crontab -e`). What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: I think this question would be better on http://askubuntu.com/ or http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your package can simply put a file in `/etc/cron.d/`

The text file should contain something like this, to run a command every 10 minutes:

```
*/10 * * * * root /path/to/command
```

Google 'cron format' for more info, and yes, this belongs in askubuntu or superuser.

You need to add the username (root) to the line, as shown above. Apparently this is necessary for files in cron.d, but I can't find a definitive document.**

cron should pick this new job up automatically.

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to restart the CRON service or anything after adding a file in cron.d ?

Comment: No you shouldn't need to, but I just checked and realised my answer was wrong. I had to add the username before the command before this worked. Hope that helps... Note that the file should be owned by root aswell.

Comment: Can I add multiple of these lines in a single file?

Comment: sure. To see an example type `man 5 crontab` or see here: http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/crontab/

Comment: why use root?....Can you please explain

Comment: It's just an example. Use root if you need to, and if not, use another user. But you'll need to make sure that user exists, which is a separate question (hint: postinst)